# Differences between readOGR and st_read

Tags: r, dataframe, gis, shapefile

I am starting to work with R and shapefiles, I have seen that there are two ways to load a shapefile, **readOGR** and **st_read**....could you please explain to me what is the difference between both methods and which one is more recommended to work in GIS?

thanks in advance.
PD: I am a beginner in R, usually i work with arcGis or QGis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this depends on whether you would like to work with `sf` or `sp` (I recommend the former). Both functions read in shapefiles, but `st_read` reads them as class `sf` and `readOGR` from `rgdal` reads them as `sp`.

I recommend reading up on [sf](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/), and using it instead of sp, but then again, it certainly depends on what you want to do.